# Why does null reference print as "null"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In println, here o.toString() throws NPE but o1, does not. Why?

```
public class RefTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = null;
        Object o1 = null;
        System.out.println(o.toString()); //throws NPE
        System.out.print(o1); // does not throw NPE
    }
}
```

Comment: It's [all in the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It might help showing you the bytecode. Take a look at the following `javap` output of your class:

```
> javap -classpath target\test-classes -c RefTest

Compiled from "RefTest.java"
public class RefTest extends java.lang.Object{
public RefTest();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   aconst_null
   1:   astore_1
   2:   aconst_null
   3:   astore_2
   4:   getstatic       #17; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   7:   aload_1
   8:   invokevirtual   #23; //Method java/lang/Object.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   11:  invokevirtual   #27; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   14:  getstatic       #17; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   17:  aload_2
   18:  invokevirtual   #33; //Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   21:  return

}
```

Just looking at the main method, you can see the lines of interest are where `Code` is 8 and 33.

Code 8 shows the bytecode for you calling `o.toString()`. Here `o` is `null` and so any attempt on a method invocation on `null` results in a `NullPointerException`.

Code 18 shows your `null` object being passed as a parameter to the `PrintStream.print()` method. Looking at the source code for this method will show you why this does *not* result in the NPE:

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

and `String.valueOf()` will do this with `null`s:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

So you can see there is a test there which deals with `null`, and prevents an NPE.

Comment: You're welcome. I often find looking at the `javap` output can be fairly insightful. Especially when using things like AspectJ and other code weaving technologies - just to see exactly what they've done to my code!

Comment: no need to look at the code. It's all in the documentation. `PrintStream::println` says that it calls `String.valueOf`, which explicitly states: "if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned."

Answer (score 6):

It's because [`print(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29) uses [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) for the conversion (aside: after the conversion [`println(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) would behave as though [`print(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) was called, `print(Object)` effectively uses `write(int)`). `String.valueOf(Object)` doesn't throw the NPE like `o.toString()` does and is instead defined to return `"null"` for a null parameter.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(o.toString())
```

`o.toString()` is trying to dereference a null object to convert it to a string, before passing it to `println`.

```
System.out.print(o1);
```

The `print` being called is the `print(Object)` variant, which is itself checking that the object is not null before proceeding.