# Why java prints null string as "null" instead of throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, outputstream, system.out

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does null reference print as “null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374363/why-does-null-reference-print-as-null)

This is specified in java API.  I wonder if this is for compatibility with previous versions of java, or has some other important reasons.

Comment: What if I have two strings, str1 = null, str2 = "null", and send both through an OutputStream, and on the other end test if the received values are the same?

Comment: Your question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374363/why-does-null-reference-print-as-null).

Comment: Another must read post - http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/

Comment: @stackoverflow - *"What if ..."* - if you find yourself in that situation, then you need to be using a better way to pass your data.  (Encoding stuff as strings and parsing them at the other end is a clunky way to pass information.)

Comment: Java does not print any Strings. And, for the convenient `null` to `"null"` conversion: you have to blame the `String.valueOf(Object obj)` method for this behaviour ;)

Answer (score 3):

When converting to a `String`, having `null` in the message is often more useful than throwing a `NullPointerException` as you can at least see the rest of the message.  The difference is likely to be a pragmatic decision.

Comment: I love pragmatic decisions! :)