# How do I read (i.e. understand) this Java array?

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

```
String[][][] arr  = 
{{ { "a", "b" , "c"}, { "d", "e", null } },{ {"x"}, null },{{"y"}},{ { "z","p"}, {} }};
```

I've reason to believe that something like this is going to come up on an exam eventually but in +10 years of coding, I've never seen such a horror. I sure could use some tips for mentally parsing this, so that I can figure out what it really means in my head. Sure, I could run it through IntelliJ but I won't have it available.

For the record, this makes perfect sense to me:

```
int[][] twoD = { { 1, 2, 3} , { 4, 5, 6, 7}, { 8, 9, 10 } };
```

Comment: It's an array of String matricies (2D arrays).  Exams try to get you to use your basic knowledge to figure out puzzles like this.  It's unlikely that anyone would ever code a such a thing.

Comment: Imagine you had an ASCII roguelike game with multiple floors and multiple rooms, and each room a grid with possible objects represented as single character string for any object or creature or null for nothing important. And you wanted to save the state of the game map. This structure would be one way of doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend adding some indentation, which will help you keep track of what's at what level of this nested array:

```
String[][][] arr  =  {
    {
        { "a", "b", "c" },
        { "d", "e", null }
    },
    {
        { "x" },
        null
    },
    {
        { "y" }
    },
    {
        { "z", "p" },
        {}
    }
};
```

Does that help? I find this makes it easier to visualize the data structure and to answer questions like "What's the value of `arr[1][0][0]`?"

You can read the type `String[][][]` as "an array of arrays of arrays of strings," or perhaps "a three-dimensional array of strings."

Comment: It might. I tried doing that on my own earlier and got lost pretty quick. Will try again.

Comment: @smarx, I'm not sure whether I should edit your answer in order to add some commentary and a reading example, so I wrote an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will understand more from this, i can see your array like this :

```
String[] arr0 = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] arr1 = {"d", "e", null};
String[] arr2 = {"x"};
String[] arr3 = null;
String[] arr4 = {"y"};
String[] arr5 = {"z", "p"};
String[] arr6 = {};

String[][] arr0_1 = {arr0, arr1};//-->>  {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", null}}
String[][] arr2_3 = {arr2, arr3};//-->>  {{"x"}, null}
String[][] arr4_4 = {arr4};      //-->>  {{"y"}}
String[][] arr5_6 = {arr5, arr6};//-->>  {{"z", "p"}, {}}

String[][][] arr = {arr0_1, arr2_3, arr4_4, arr5_6};
```

which is equivalent to

```
String[][][] arr
        = {
            {//----------------------------
                {"a", "b", "c"},//arr0    |
                                        //|---->arr0_1
                {"d", "e", null}//arr1    |
            },//---------------------------

            {//----------------------------
                {"x"},//arr2              |
                                        //|---->arr2_3
                null  //arr3              |
            },//---------------------------

            {//----------------------------
                {"y"}//arr4               |---->arr4_4
            },//---------------------------

            {//----------------------------
                {"z", "p"},//arr5         |
                                        //|---->arr5_6
                {}//arr6                  |
            }//---------------------------
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the array will help to figure out that as a matrix of rows and cols

```
String[][][] arr  = 
{
    {{"a", "b" , "c"}, {"d", "e", null} },
    {{"x"           }, null             },
    {{"y"           }                   },
    {{"z", "p"      }, {                }}
};
```

2 Cols, 4 rows

> element at 0,0: `{"a", "b" , "c"}`
>
> element at 0,1: `{"d", "e", null}`
>
> element at 1,0: `{"x"}`
>
> element at 1,1: `null`

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][][] arr = {

            // arr[0]
            {
                    /* arr[0][0] */
                    {
                            /* arr[0][0][0] */ "a",
                            /* arr[0][0][1] */ "b",
                            /* arr[0][0][2] */ "c"
                    },

                    /* arr[0][1] */
                    {
                            /* arr[0][1][0] */ "d",
                            /* arr[0][1][1] */ "e",
                            /* arr[0][1][2] */ null
                    }
            },

            // arr[1]
            {
                    /* arr[1][0] */
                    {
                            /* arr[1][0][0] */ "x"
                    },

                    /* arr[1][1] */
                    null
            },

            // arr[2]
            {
                    /* arr[2][0] */
                    {
                            /* arr[2][0][0] */ "y"
                    }
            },

            // arr[3]
            {
                    /* arr[3][0] */
                    {
                            /* arr[3][0][0] */ "z",
                            /* arr[3][0][1] */ "p"
                    },

                    /* arr[3][1] */
                    {}
            }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @smarx answer:

```
// [][][] is an array of 2D arrays
String[][][] arr = { // begin declaration of arr
    // first 2D array
    {
        {"[0][0][0]", "[0][0][1]", "[0][0][2]"},
        {"[0][1][0]", "[0][1][1]", null, "[0][1][3]"}
    },
    // second 2D array
    {
        {"[1][0][0]", "[1][0][1]"},
        null // we should check for this when reading
    },
    // third 2D array
    {
        {"[2][0][0]", "[2][0][1]", "[2][0][2]"}
    },
    // fourth 2D array
    {
        {"[3][0][0]", "[3][0][1]"},
        {}
    },
    // fifth 2D array
    {
        {"[4][0][0]", "[4][0][1]", "[4][0][2]"},
        {"[4][1][0]", "[4][1][1]"},
        {"[4][2][0]", "[4][2][1]", "[4][2][2]"}
    }   
};

// Reading the 3D array, as: [x][y][z]
for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
        // one of our 2D arrays has a null array, 
        // declared in the line: {"[0][1][0]", "[0][1][1]", null, "[0][1][3]"}
        if (arr[x][y] != null) {
            for (int z = 0; z < arr[x][y].length; z++) {
                System.out.println(arr[x][y][z]);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("null 2D array");
        }
    }
}
```

We must check for the null arrays because we are trying to access something and it doesn't exist. The null string doesn't need to be checked (for printing) because Java will already make this check when printing, see [why null reference prints as "null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7374363/6626496)