# Why overriden toString is not called while printing null reference

Tags: java, oop

I Know while printing the object, java calls the toString() method internally.

But after overriding the toString() method, Java not calling the overriden toString() method for the null reference.
Please see the below code for reference,

```
public class Sample1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Test test1 = null;
        Test test2 = new Test();
        System.out.println(test1);
        System.out.println(test2);
    }
}
class Test {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

The output of the above program is,

```
null
test
```

Can any one please explain why the overriden toString() method is not called for the null reference.

Comment: [Why does null reference print as “null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374363/why-does-null-reference-print-as-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call any method over a null referenced object, NPE will be thrown.

The `System.out.println` uses `String.valueOf()` method implicitly, which returns `null` literal for null reference.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

`toString` is a method belonging to **instances** of your class. But your `test1` **variable** does not point anywhere. It is still pointing to `null`, not to any actual instance of the `Test` class.

It is impossible to get hands on a `toString` using `test1`, since the variable does not refer any instance which has this method.

---

### Illustration

Let me illustrate the correlation between variables and actual instances. And that the methods actually belong to instances, not to variables.

```
test1 ----> null

test2 ----> instance of Test (created by new Test())
                     |---> toString()
                     |---> hashCode()
                     |---> ... // all methods belonging to a Test instance
```

---

### `println`

`System.out.println` prints out `null` because it detects that the variable is pointing nowhere and falls back to a default print of `"null"` as text. Similar to:

```
void println(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        println("null");
    } else {
        println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

If you are curious, you can lookup the actual code:

1. [PrintStream#println(Object)](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/io/printstream.java#L-895), calling `String.valueOf(x)`
2. [String#valueOf(Object)](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/lang/string.java#L-2786) doing the *magic*

   ```
   return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type which 'null' is an 'instanceof'. In practice you can simply pretend that it's "merely a special literal that can be of any reference type". So 2 objects of different type both set to null will be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in `java.lang.String.java` `class` we have a method likewise,

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

This method implicitly called by `System.out.println(...) ->  String.valueOf(x);`